# How to replace Array in useState?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I want make program that table content is changed by user's select. So I put empty array in useState, like this.

```html
    const [statInfo, setStatInfo] = useState([]);
```

And select html code:

```
                    <select
                        name="statSelect"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            handleChange(e);
                            setStat();
                        }}>
                        <option value="0to60">무각 60</option>
                        <option value="1to60">1각 60</option>
                        <option value="2to60">2각 60</option>
                    </select>
```

When I select option, data will be changed. But I don't no how to do it with useState.
These are data

```html
    const stat = [
         [11421, 1059, 782, "10%", "50%", "10%", "25%"],
         [11992, 1112, 821, "15%", "55%", "20%", "30%"],
         [10401, 1114, 1049, "20%", "30%", "35%", "25%"]
    ];
```

And my React code:

```
    async function setStat() {
    console.log('calling');
    if (stat === "무각 60") {
        await setStatInfo(stat[0]);
        console.log(statInfo);
    } else if (stat === "1각 60") {
        await setStatInfo(stat[1]);
        console.log(statInfo);
    } else {
        await setStatInfo(stat[2]);
        console.log(statInfo);
    }
}
```

I tried using map. But I don't know how to use map, too.

Is there a function or way to change the entire array each time?

Comment: `await setStatInfo(`   That `await` is doing nothing..

Comment: `console.log(statInfo);`  statInfo won't change on the next line, it will be on the next render.   You maybe need to read up more about React render lifecycles.

Comment: If you're using an Array as state, you should change it like this: `setStatInfo([...statInfo, newElement])`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I'm just on my way to fix it! And you mean, the value went into useState correctly but not reflected in console.log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can handle this action in your handleChange :

```
  handleChange(e) {
    stat.forEach(async (att) => {
      if(att === e.target.value){
        await setStatInfo(att)
      }
    })
  }
```

If you can't and you want to use your setStat function I guess you can make something like :

```
 setStat = async (e) => {
   stat.forEach(async (att) => {
     if(att === e.target.value){
       await setStatInfo(att)
     }
   })
 }
```

And call `this.setStat(e)` in your onChange

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason why you should use async in the function setStat (correct me if I'm wrong!).

You should have selection like this:

```
<select onChange={handleChange}>
     <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
     <option value="lime">Lime</option>
     <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
</select>
```

Then you can have `handleChange` function that update the state:

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    if(event.target.value === "grapefruit"){
        setStatInfo([...stat[0]]);
    } else if (event.target.value === "lime"){
        setStatInfo([...stat[1]]);
    } else if (event.target.value === "coconut"){
        setStatInfo([...stat[2]]);
    }
}
```

Notice that I'm using arrow function (regular function doesn't work). And in `react`, we don't call function, we pass function.

You can also set default value for `select`. For example,

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("default value");
```

Then pass this into your select form:

```
<select value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
```

I need to put function into curly braces {} so React can tell the difference between Javascript (within braces) and JSX.

After this, you can return the component (I assume that you're using function component):

```
return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
         <select value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
            <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
            <option value="lime">Lime</option>
            <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

To update only certain index of an array as an expression, I'd use `Array.prototype.map()` with index:

```js
const indexToUpdate = 1;
const newValue = 'foo';

setStatInfo(statInfo.map(
  (value, index) => index === indexToUpdate ? newValue : value
));
```

It doesn't make for a copy-paste answer, but I believe you can make use of it.